# Spark SQL - aggregate columns into dictionary

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame:

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT id, color, cnt
FROM ( 
  VALUES ('A','green', 5),
         ('A','yellow', 4),
         ('A','yellow',2),
         ('B','blue', 3),
         ('B','green',4),
         ('B','blue',1) 
) as T (id, color, cnt)
""")
```

and would like to aggregate it in such a way that for each `id` key I have a dictionary of counts and sums of `cnt` column. So the output would be:

```
+---+-----------------------------------------+
| id|         color_cnt | color_sum           |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|  B|{blue:2, green:1}  | {blue:4, green:4}   | 
|  A|{green:1, yellow:2}| {green:5, yellow:6} |
+---+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Are there any **Spark SQL** functions that would help me achieve what I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions `to_json` and `map_from_arrays` would be helpful for you. If you want a map type in the dataframe, simply remove `to_json`.

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT
    id,
    to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(color), collect_list(count))) count,
    to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(color), collect_list(sum))) sum 
FROM (

    SELECT id, color, count(1) count, sum(cnt) sum
    FROM ( 
      VALUES ('A','green', 5),
             ('A','yellow', 4),
             ('A','yellow',2),
             ('B','blue', 3),
             ('B','green',4),
             ('B','blue',1) 
    ) as T (id, color, cnt)
    GROUP BY id, color)

GROUP BY id
""").show(truncate=False)

+---+----------------------+----------------------+
|id |count                 |sum                   |
+---+----------------------+----------------------+
|B  |{"blue":2,"green":1}  |{"blue":4,"green":4}  |
|A  |{"yellow":2,"green":1}|{"yellow":6,"green":5}|
+---+----------------------+----------------------+
```